# List all table names in a database which begin with "pages_backup"

Tags: php, mysql

I need to provide a list of all the backups I have available for a certain website.  Each backup is a table with a name such as `pages_backup_09_5_11`.

I'd like to know what SQL I need to write to return the names of all the tables beginning with `pages_backup`.

All I really need is the list of dates, i.e. the `09_5_11` bit.

There are other tables in the database that I don't want returned.

Comment: +1 for the super useful questions:P What a coincidence :D I am doing the same exact thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `SHOW TABLES` with a condition

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'pages_backup%'
```